# how to count unique values from user input in python?

Tags: python

How to count unique values from user input in python ?

```py
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    b = input()
```

O/p should be print unique value count.

Comment: How would you count unique values if they weren't from a user input? It seems the user input is a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input())
unique_values = {input() for x in range(a)}
print(len(unique_values))
```

Set comprehension will automatically ignore all the duplicates, thus giving you all the distinct values that were entered.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
a = int(input("Input number like 458975634: "))

uniq_numbers_qty = len(set(list(str(a))))

print(uniq_numbers_qty)
```

Explanations to the code:

- if a == 458975634
- str(a) - converts int 458975634 to string '458975634'
- list(...) - converts string '458975634' to list ['4','5','8','9','7','5','6','3','4']
- set(...) - removes duplicates from list
- len(...) - counts items

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get multiple inputs and identify the unique values the following will help you.

```
>>> data_ = list(map(int,input('enter the series: ').split()))
enter the series: 20 21 22 22 1 2 1 2
>>> len(set(data_))
5
>>>
```